# Chunk comma delimeted flatfile of size 20+MB in Azure logic app and convert to Json - ActionResultsSizeLimitExceeded

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a flat file in blob with below structure with header and body content. And this file can go up to the size of 20+MB. I need to Split this file for every 4000 records and convert into Json format.

"000","IN",04963,"xyz_abc",20210602,034425,278233

"803","IN","123456",0,"00002",0,1.519,"INR",1,

"803","IN","123456",0,"00004",0,1.579,"INR",1,

"803","IN","232323",0,"00002",0,1.519,"EUR",1,

"803","IN","232323",0,"00004",0,1.579,"EUR",1,

I am trying with the below approach
Step1 - read the blob content and convert to XML using XML Schema (using integration account schema & flat file decoding)
Step2 - Chunk XML for each 4000 record and convert to desired Json format and save it to processed Blob

But I am getting below issue in the Step1 while flat file decoding even though the file size is 20MB, but the restriction is 200MB.

ActionResultsSizeLimitExceeded. The action 'Flat_File_Decoding' has results size of more that '228151576' bytes. This exceeded the maximum size '209715200' allowed.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the error is about the size of the results, not about the size of the source file.

20 MB CSV file can be easily converted to 200+ MB XML file, depending on the size of the tags used in the XML file.

E.g. while the size of the first line in your example is only 50 characters, the size of the following linearized XML that contains the same data is 455 characters:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ReagllyLongTag00 xmlns="http://ReallyLongNamespaceWellNotReallyLong"><ReallyLongRecord xmlns=""><ReallyLongTag01>000</ReallyLongTag01><ReallyLongTag02>IN</ReallyLongTag02><ReallyLongTag03>04963</ReallyLongTag03><ReallyLongTag04>xyz_abc</ReallyLongTag04><ReallyLongTag05>20210602</ReallyLongTag05><ReallyLongTag06>034425</ReallyLongTag06><ReallyLongTag07>278233</ReallyLongTag07></ReallyLongRecord></ReagllyLongTag00>`

Azure Functions tend to manipulate data from large files much better than Logic Apps.

Comment: Thank you @10p :) Is there any other way to convert the above flat file to desired Json format given this file size

Comment: @Sridhar With 20+MB files (which can at some point easily become 50+MB files) I'd suggest to use Azure Functions because using other options such as Liquid template transformations can fail you as well, but let me redirect you to the answer in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/72756/other-ways-to-convert-csv-to-json-more-performance.html - it contains a sample of a simple JS code that could be adjusted and used in your Logic App, it could be exactly what you need.

Comment: @Sridhar if you appreciate this answer, please don't forget to choose it as the correct one (it's the "V" green button)

Comment: Thats Correct. thats the size of the results, not the source. We have chosen ADF over Logic App to resolve the issue. Thanks @10p